# Grails on MariaDB field has value but fetched null

Tags: grails, mariadb

I'm having a weird problem that I can not understand. I create Job objects and store them in MariaDB. There is a "userName" field that I store in the object. I can see that the value is successfully set in Maria DB's HeidiSQL panel. However, by Job.findById(jobId) returns me a Job object which has **userName=null**.

```
class Job {
    String userName;    
    public Job(String name){
        userName=name;
        init();//initiate some transient fields that are omitted here
        //println "Job is initiated "+this.id;
    }
    static mapping={
        id generator:"identity"
    }
    static constraints = {
        //userName(blank:true,nullable:true);
    }
}
```

The Job object is created by JobController and persisted.

```
class JobController {

static scaffolding=true;
public static Job initiateJob(String name){
    Job job=new Job(name)

    job.save(flush:true);
    if(job.hasErrors())
        println job.errors;
    println "New job initiated "+job.id+": "+job.userName;
    return job;
}
//I use the jobId to keep track of the job in session
public static Job trackJob(String jobId){
    Long l=Long.parseLong(jobId);
    Job job=Job.find("from Job as j where j.id=:id",[id:l]);//**The job object has userName=null!**
    //Job job=Job.findById(l);//**This doesn't work either**
    if(job==null){
        println "Job is not found. Need to check the error.";

    }
    return job;
}
}
```

This is very confusing. When I directly check the DB I see the row with userName column so I think the row is indeed persisted. I'm not sure what might be wrong with my straightforward logic. I'm using Grails 2.4.4. The scope of this JobController is singleton.

Appreciate your help!

**Edit:**
I've tried the following and the result was unexpected:

```
def jobList=Job.findAll("from Job as j where j.userName is not null");
println jobList.size()+" "+jobList;
```

The result is:`1 [Job: id:1 user name:null]`

I can hardly understand why **the result of not null returns items with userName=null**. What's the mistake I made?

Comment: Have you tried `j.user_name`? Is the column named userName or user_name? Becuase I use postgres and the table puts underscore when I have a camel case in a domain classs.

Comment: @monty_bean I tried but user_name cannot be resolved to a column by hibernate, which makes sense actually. Hibernate converts camel case to underscore and just uses this between itself and db.